# how to customize dialog window nsis

Tags: windows, winapi, resize, nsis, customdialog

I am a beginner in NSIS.
I want to make an NSIS installer in which I want to open a web page url on which there are some flash games which I want user to play. For this I am using     nsWeb     plugin but it doesnt seem to support flash files. So I want to know if there is some other plugin available for the same.
Also I want to resize the dialog window and the area showing web page to around 600x600. I am able to resize the dialog window using win api's func SetWindowPos but problem is that it is only resizing the outer dialog and not the internal area displaying the web page. So is there any way I can do that. I know we can achieve it using Resource hacker, but I want to know some other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Resource Hacker is the easiest way to resize an installer.

I think nsweb should allow flash, but you can try to use the Flash plugin for Innosetup like in this example:

http://wenku.baidu.com/view/fb800d6baf1ffc4ffe47acbd.html

Comment: actually nsWeb uses IE's instance. So it is blocking swf files from non trusted website. That can be dealt.
But resizing is still a problem, Resource Hacker is not working fine and I wish to avoid using it if there is some better option.